# How to use NSLogger LogMessageF function

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslogger

I'm trying to integrate NSLogger into my app.

From the [Documentation](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger/wiki/NSLogger-API):

```
void LogMessage(NSString *tag, int level, NSString *format, ...);
void LogMessageF(const char *file, int line, const char *function, NSString *tag, int level, NSString *format, ...);
```

Log a string to the default logger. Specifies a tag (can be nil) and a level, for advanced filtering (i.e. log important messages to level 0, more debug info to level 1, etc).The ..F variant can report the file, line and/or function name the log call was originally made from. Typically, you’ll use the standard **FILE**, **LINE** and **PRETTY_FUNCTION** compiler defines.

I tried to use the function as:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    LogMessage(@"map view just loaded", 0, @"map view loaded");
    LogMessageF(nil,50,nil,@"tag mapvc",1,@"testing f ormat");
   }
```

They both appear to be same. I'm expecting that LogMessageF should also show the line number along with the function name where it was called as mentioned in the documentation.

Instead of passing nil, I also tried passing the class name and function name, but in the logger, it didn't display those details.

Here is the screenshot of the NSLOggeR:

[image]